# Java JNA Dereference Pointer

Tags: java, c++, jna

Well I have the following code in c++

```
uintptr_t buf;

if ((reason = vm_read(task, (uintptr_t) &start, sizeof(int), &buf, &bytesRead)) != KERN_SUCCESS) {
    cout << "Failed to read: " << reason << endl;
}

cout << "Step 2 (after write, should = 100): " << (*(int *) buf) << endl;
```

Where it prints in step 2, I deref the buf pointer and convert to its int value.

I was wondering how can I do this in Java using JNA?

I've tried the following but it doesn't print the correct value.

```
    IntByReference o = new IntByReference();
    MemoryBuffer buffer = Cacheable.buffer(4);
    System.out.println(mac.vm_read(process.task(), new Pointer(140734594927432L), 4,  buffer, o));
    System.out.println(Pointer.nativeValue(buffer));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read the proper value, I had to first call buffer.getPointer(0).getInt()

Ex:

```
IntByReference o = new IntByReference();
MemoryBuffer buffer = Cacheable.buffer(4);
System.out.println(mac.vm_read(process.task(), new Pointer(140734594927432L), 4,  buffer, o));
System.out.println(buffer.getPointer(0).getInt());
```

Comment: You should really use `Memory` and explicitly allocate the size of buffer you require.  Using `PointerByReference` gives you a buffer the size of a pointer.

Comment: When using the `Memory` class gives me the wrong value like I had in the original question. It returns `551456768(different every time)` instead of the actual value. Using `PointerByReference` fixes that.

Comment: Show your work, and indicate what you expect and what went wrong, which will make it easier to pinpoint exactly where you're going wrong.  `PointerByReference` simply wraps specific semantics around a `Memory` buffer, so to say `Memory` fails where `PointerByReference` works is insufficient.